# is this possible to handle stack overflow error?

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

```
enter code here
static int i=10;
    static void m1()
    {
        try {
            if(i>=0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i--;
            } 
            
            m1();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("hii");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        m1();
    }
```

1)by using this way we can handle stack overflow error but actually java doesn't allow us to handle error.
2)second point is when we get an exception in try block then an then only respected catch block will get executed but in our scenario we get an error in try block but catch block is executing when we use throwable e instead of exception e.

if anybody knows the reason behind this situation then  plz text on it..

Comment: I do not understand either points. Does the code "work" and catch the StackOverflowError or does something unexpected happen?

Comment: The right way to deal with a StackOverflowError is to stop it happening in the first place.

Comment: Point is that java says that error cant be handeled but in this case error get handeled....

Answer (score 1):

> is this possible to handle stack overflow error?

Yes. StackOverflowError isn't special: it's a Throwable, so you can catch it.

The problem you've got here is that you're catching and handling the StackOverflowError at the very tip of the stack (that is, when it's *just about* to overflow).

You get a StackOverflowError when invoking `m1()` because you can't invoke `m1()` any more times; but it's nothing to do with invoking `m1()` per se, it's to do with invoking *any* method.

So, when you try to handle it, you're invoking a method (`System.out.println`), and you get another StackOverflowError, which is thrown from the `catch`, not the `try`.

You shouldn't attempt to handle StackOverflowErrors: instead, restructure your logic so you never get anywhere near overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting `StackOverflowError` because there is no base condition in your recursion to return. You are just calling `m1()` indefinitely.
Since you are only interested in values of i>=0, you can modify m1 like:

```
static void m1() {
    if(i<0)return;
    try {
        if(i>=0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            i--;
        } 
        m1();
    }catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("hii");
    }
}
```